# VB Get range by cell name

Tags: excel, vbscript

while in the early stages of my script I ran into the problem of wanting to get the range of cells in a column dynamically because I am constantly adding new cells. I looked into getting the range by column name but I get the error, "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". I might be understanding the range by column name wrong, does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub autoFill()
Sheets("Unit #2").Range("SUBSYSTEM").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("A1")

Sheets("Unit #2").Range("B2:B38").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("B1")

End Sub
```

Where the first line shows where I am trying to get the contents of the column, "SUBSYSTEM" and the second shows how I would do it with the fixed range, which does work.

Comment: Did you name the entire column using named ranges, or is "SUBSYSTEM" merely the column header?

Comment: @JNevill It is just the column header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Unit #2 worksheet and select the column header label cell with *SUBSYSTEM*.

Choose the Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager command. When it opens, choose New.

Use *SUBSYSTEM* as the name; leave it as workbook scope and use the following for Refers to:

```
'for text values in the SUBSYSTEM column
='Unit #2'!$Z$1:INDEX('Unit #2'!$Z:$Z, MATCH("zzz", 'Unit #2'!$Z:$Z))
'for number values in the SUBSYSTEM column
='Unit #2'!$Z$1:INDEX('Unit #2'!$Z:$Z, MATCH(1e99, 'Unit #2'!$Z:$Z))
```

Click OK. Now your code should work.

[image]

> Note that you will have to substitute the actual SUBSYSTEM column letter identifier in place of **Z** (5 places).

Comment: Where you have the '=' signs there, am I setting this equal to an an object?

Comment: You are defining a **dynamic named range** from the first cell in the column to the last value (either text or number) in that column. After defining the name youcan  test using GoTo (F5) to *go to SUBSYSTEM* and it will select that column of values.